# change background color and save pdf with new bg color

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader

I know how to change background color in adobe reader and other software. Adding on to that, I want to know how to save that new background color for use, and that pdf file on a tablet or any other pdf reader with the same background color.

Comment: Which software are you prepared to use?

Comment: any software , not important.

Comment: Then take a general-propose PDF library for the programming context of your choice, e.g. iText for java, and use it to draw a rectangle behind the page context, in case of iText using the UnderContent of a PdfStamper.

Comment: would be better if a simple way for change all page bg color .